# fread from char buffer

Tags: c++

I have file which has some content written by fwrite in 'w' mode.

I know that I can simply read it back using fread again but I am wondering if there is a way to read the entire file into a std::string/char buffer and then fread from it.

I admit that this is a wierd requirement, the file is actually stored remotely and I don't want to fetch the file to disk and then fread from it due to latency concerns.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one please. They're not the same at all in practice.

Comment: Why would you want to `fread` from a `char *` - would you not want to use `strcpy` or `memcpy` from it?

Comment: What? If you already have the contents in an array or string, you can just access them? Not sure how you came to this strange idea, but please read up on the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @FelixPalmen: If you have existing code that expects to read from a stream, it can be a lot easier to continue to read from something stream-like, rather than completely re-writing it all.

Answer (score 0):

Reading into a string and then supporting `fread` from it is not supported, so doing it would require some non-portable hacking on the standard library code.

Reading it into a string and then supporting `istream::read` from it is fully supported, so it's trivial to do. Personally, I'd probably use iostreams for the whole operation though. Unless the remote file is really huge, I'd probably do something like this:

```
// Open remote for reading:
std::ifstream remote_file("filename");

std::stringstream buffer;

// get the data from the remote file into the stringstream:
buffer << remote_file.rdbuf();

// read some data from the stringstream:
char input_buffer[256];
buffer.read(input_buffer, sizeof(input_buffer));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about fetching the file using the `system()` and `scp` function?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char command[90];

    strcpy(command, "scp remoteUser@remoteServer:remote/path/to/file.txt local/path/to/newFile.txt");
    system(command);

    // Then read as you normally would using fread

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a few examples using the [system()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm) function.

And here is the man for [ssh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) command.